# URL router and relative URL's

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I've written my Route class and it works perfectly when starts from DOCUMENT_ROOT of the server. But now I have to use it from deep directory and problems were start. Now I'm gonna show you my index.php and route.php files. I wanna ask you how could I use it without manually writing of directory on server? (of course without parsing). Or in general, how could I start it to work from any directories on server? 
**DIR** shows us directory on the local machine or how it works?

> /Users/username/PhpstormProjects/projectname

But it works with URI like

> username/PhpstormProjects/projectname/

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);

//session_start();
include_once 'components/route.php';

//put here the directory with index.php (form from ROOT: cat1/ca2/ )
$GLOBALS['base_dir'] = 'username/PhpstormProjects/projectname/';

$router = new Route();
$router->start();
```

**route.php**

```
<?php

class Route
{
    private $aRouts = [

    ];

    public function __construct()
    {

        $routes = './config/routes.php';
        $this->aRouts = include($routes);

    }

    private function getURL()
    {
        //get request string
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

        }
        return null;
    }


    public function start() {

        $uri = $this->getURL();

        foreach ($this->aRouts as $uriPattern => $path) {
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~",$uri)) {


                $url = $GLOBALS['base_dir'];
                //cut the first part of URL with directory
                $cutDir = preg_replace("~$url~","","$uri");

                //black magic (change reg exp)
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~","$path","$cutDir");

                $segments = explode('/',$internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments).'Controller';

                //take name of file with class

                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                //take name of method

                $actionName = 'action'.ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $parametrs = $segments;

                //connect files
                $controllerFile = './controllers/'.$controllerName.'.php';

                if(file_exists($controllerFile))
                {
                    include_once $controllerFile;
                }

                //create new controller object
                $classObject = new $controllerName();
                $result = call_user_func_array(array($classObject, $actionName), $parametrs);

                if($result != NULL){
                    break;
                }


            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in all your pages

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Users/username/PhpstormProjects/projectname";
```

Now the path will have the full path. So you can use this on any pages and won't make an issue.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will add the root path with the portion of your path. So that it always will refer to the full path

Comment: but how could I put second part automatically? and by the way - DOCUMENT_ROOT it's root of my MAMP server for example, but __DIR__ it's the catalog on my mac. How it will work together?

Comment: This will be applicable for your local server where the site resides at the `projectname` folder. Once you move to a live server, you may need to change this structure. For that, you need to test the domain name and assign the path variable.

Comment: ok, I got it. But what could I do for starting application from anywhere and It isn't depends on variable of string? Launch form BOX (OEM)